# Why is the following line of code OK in VS2010 but not VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, unity-container

Unity version 2.1.505.0 in both WPF projects. One in 2010 & other in 2012. 
In 2010 fine but 2012 I get Error "The non-generic method 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer.Resolve(System.Type, string, params Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride[])' cannot be used with type arguments"???

```
return this.Container.Resolve<Shell>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to add using for the Unity namespace as well as Prism.UnityExtensions. Answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3376054/1775191) on StackOverflow.